# How to convert unusual 24 hour date time format in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe column full datetime type that are in the format

```
2016Oct03:14:38:33
```

Right now, the data type of this column of the dataframe is String. I would like to convert it into datetime in order to be able perform some numerical operations like subtractions on them. I have tried specifying the format while using pd.to_datetime but as the time is in a 24 hr format, it is throwing up an error. What is the best way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter [`format`](http://strftime.org/):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':['2016Oct03:14:38:33',
                            '2016Oct03:14:38:33',
                            '2016Oct03:14:38:33']})

print (df)
                dates
0  2016Oct03:14:38:33
1  2016Oct03:14:38:33
2  2016Oct03:14:38:33

df.dates = pd.to_datetime(df.dates, format='%Y%b%d:%H:%M:%S')
print (df)
                dates
0 2016-10-03 14:38:33
1 2016-10-03 14:38:33
2 2016-10-03 14:38:33
```

Answer (score 4):

There doesn't seem to be anything unusual about the time format at all; 24 hour is absolutely standard.

Just the normal strptime is fine:

```
datetime.strptime(my_date, '%Y%b%d:%H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicated question

Use datetime.strptime

Ex:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_object = datetime.strptime('2016Oct03:14:38:33', '%Y%b%d:%H:%M:%S')
```

Doc : https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: It would have been better if  you provided the sample example with the date format user is using.